# How to handle collection with primary key in hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a restaurant app with spring-boot and hibernate. My simple restaurant class looks like following.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String name;
    String city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant")
    List<CustomerOrder> customerOrders;

}
```

Now, i want every restaurant class to have a list of menu items. Item object would look like following.

```
public class Item {
  @Id
  Long id;
  String name;
}
```

I've already tried @ElementCollection but i can't set primary key in embedded types such as Item.

How can i have list of items with unique identifier of each item attached to restaurant?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to map it with a `OneToMany` in the same way you have mapped `List<CustomerOrder>`... but maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: simplifying my question , how would you handle the list of items (food items) in the restaurant entity where you can uniquely identify each food item in the list.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the scenario in which 2 restaurants offer the same item and you want to uniquely identify it? For example 2 restaurants offering Pizza and you want that Pizza object/row to be the same for both restaurants? If this is the case, you need a `ManyToMany` relationship.